# Joomla 2.5 - Hide the backend error message after few seconds

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and I use below code to output error messages to the user at the backend.

```
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('Error Message goes here'));
```

What I want to do is hide the error message after few seconds. How can I do it? Do I have to use jQuery or Mootools ? Does it already contains in the Joomla ?

I'm new to Joomla & Hope someone will help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not come across any inbuilt method that joomla provides for this. But you can try this-

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');</script>  
<script>jQuery("#system-message").fadeOut(4000);    </script>
```

As per comment you can try this-

```
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#system-message').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: What I want to do is wait 5 seconds and then hide the message

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Irfan answer I was able to figured it out. What he does is right away fade out the error message. What I'm doing is wait 5 secs before hiding, so that user can see the error.

```
jQuery('#system-message-container').delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
```